# Collections.sort - I have created 2 user define objects [both are of different types] and then add into arraylist , then I have tried to sort it

Tags: java, sorting, collections

> Expected Result of code is ClassCastException but Actual Result :- [Person with pid- 1 - a1-name, Person with pid- 2 - c2-name, Sorting.Employee@cdfc9c, Sorting.Employee@1837697]

`Person` class:

```
package Sorting;

public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private int pid;
    private String pname;

    public int getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(int pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public String getPname() {
        return pname;
    }

    public void setPname(String pname) {
        this.pname = pname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person with pid- " + getPid() + " - " + getPname(); 
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        return this.pid - p.pid;
    }
}
```

`Employee` class:

```
package Sorting;

public class Employee implements Comparable {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

`SortingofObjects` class:

```
package Sorting;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class SortingofObjects {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setPid(1);
        p1.setPname("a1-name");

        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.setPid(2);
        p2.setPname("c2-name");
        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        Employee e2 = new Employee();

        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
        a.add(p1);
        a.add(p2);
        a.add(e1);
        a.add(e2);
        Collections.sort(a);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: what your issue was again?

Comment: `Expected Result of code is ClassCastException` Really?

Comment: did you try to add the employee before the persons in your arraylist?

Comment: So I guess the question is, why this code won't throw a ClassCastException, because the `Comparable` implementation of `Person` is a generic type and not a raw type like in `Employee`. @njzk2 since you're on the right track here, you might think about writing an answer :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collections.sort` does not call `compareTo` on every pair in the `List`, just enough pairs to sort the `List`. As an example, run this code:

```
public class Test implements Comparable<Test> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Test> list = new ArrayList<Test>();
        list.add(new Test(1));
        list.add(new Test(2));
        list.add(new Test(3));
        list.add(new Test(4));
        Collections.sort(list);
    }

    private final int number;

    Test(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Test that) {
        System.out.println(this + ".compareTo(" + that + ")");
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + number;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
2.compareTo(1)
3.compareTo(2)
4.compareTo(3)
```

Since your `List` is in the order `Person`, `Person`, `Employee`, `Employee`, the only combination that would throw a `ClassCastException`, namely

```
Person.compareTo(Employee)
```

never occurs. If your `List` contained an `Employee` before a `Person` it would throw an exception.

Comment: if List is containing Person before Employee , will it throw exception ?

Comment: @ShivaGarg No. This is the current situation in your list. But if the `Employee` instances are before the `Person` instances, then there will be an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

If it just so happens that the sorting algorithm used only compares `Employee`s to `Person`s, and not the other way around, then it'll never throw, because `Employee.compareTo` accepts any `Object`.  You just got lucky, more or less.